# Installing postgresql 9.5.3 with homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I need to install postgresql 9.5.3 using homebrew. First I search for version of postgresql using

```
brew search postgresql

homebrew/versions/postgresql93 ✔  homebrew/versions/postgresql94
```

But I do not see my version. Could you help me please to install postgresql 9.5.3 with homebrew?

Comment: You need to input `brew update` to update Brew and then `brew install postgres` to install PostgreSQL.

Comment: but I need that specific version

Comment: ah i see, then [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) may be useful for you.

Answer (score 11):

To install  use this command on your terminal
 `brew install postgresql@9.5`

Comment: i am getting this error 
Error: postgresql@9.5 has been disabled because it is not supported upstream!